# Redirect command output to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, tshark

I have a question about redirection linux command output (tshark) directly to MySQL database.

Tshark output looks like:

```
item-1:item-2:item-3:...:item-8
```

Is there any quite simple and beautiful way to redirect this output directly to MYSQL table with the rows "item-1"..."item-N"?

Any samples would be very useful for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tshark-command|awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"};{print "insert into tbl_name (field1, field2, ..., field8) values (" $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 ");"}' > insertcmd.sql
```

alternatively:

```
tshark-command|sed 's/^/insert into tbl_name \(field1,field2,...,field8\) values \(/g'|sed 's/:/,/g'|sed 's/$/);"
```

and finally:

```
mysql dbname < insertcmd.sql
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you,this command works:
tshark-command|awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"};{print "insert into tbl_name (field1, field2, ..., field8) values (" $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7 "," $8 ");"}' > insertcmd.sql
Unfortunately additional single quotes are necessary at the "value" field, so the result must look: insert into table_name (field1,...,field8) values ('value1', 'value2',...,'value8');

How I can add them to this awk construction?

Comment: tshark-command|sed "s/^/insert into tbl_name \(field1,field2,field3,field8\) values \('/g"|sed "s/:/','/g"|sed "s/$/'\);/g"